# Jump between sections with an anchor link and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a code for make a smooth scroll with an anchor link, but what I want is make a fixed link on the window height and jump between each section available in the page. My link says *Scroll to know more*. When the user make click, it must to go to each section. My code so far is:

```
$("#over_scroll_text a").on('click', function(event) {

    // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
    //if (this.hash == "") {
      // Prevent default anchor click behavior
      event.preventDefault();

      // Store hash
      //var hash = this.hash;

      // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
      // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
      $('html, body').animate({
        //scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
        scrollTop: $(document).height() - $(window).height()
      //}, 800//, function(){

        // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
        //window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    //} // End if
});
```

No idea of what can I do from here. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Line 9, 16, and 19 shouldn't be commented out